# Parsing SVG in Opera―DOMException: NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR

Tags: html, parsing, svg

I am trying to parse a SVG-String with Opera, it works perfectly fine in FF and Chrome, but Opera gives me:

```
Uncaught exception: DOMException: NOT_SUPPORTED_ERRError
```

the code to parse the String is this:

```
var svg = ( new DOMParser() ).parseFromString( 
                svgstr.replace( /\$\{png-dir\}/g, 
                    this._vars[ 'templateurl' ] + '/batch/png' ), 'image/svg+xml' );
```

`svgstr` is the SVG (loaded via ajax, same domain) which contains `${png-dir}` in some attributes, what is replaced by a valid path.

Any Ideas?

n.b.: The SVG is created with inkscape and saved as Inkscape SVG, so it includes a whole bunch of namespaced elements and attributes, but it does not contain any element listed [here](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/opera95/svg/attributes.xml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this regressed in Presto 214 (Opera bug CORE-41250), Presto 392 has a fix for it (CORE-48402). A workaround is to use `text/xml` for the type argument.

Comment: thanks! SVG is parsed and displayed! Animation performance sucks, but better than nothing ;) Thank you!